# simple persistent stylesheet switcher

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, styleswitching

I need help writing a persistent stylesheet switcher. I have found an [article on ALA](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/) but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work!

I have three stylesheets, the default one for the layout and another two which the user will switch between (adjusting the colours). I may later add one for print but I am not there yet.

The style switcher javascript file can be found here http://www.alistapart.com/d/alternate/styleswitcher.js

I have this in the `<head>` of my page at the moment.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/styleswitcher.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alt_style1.css" title="purple" />
<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alt_style2.css" title="red" />
```

I want the user's selection to be stored in a cookie so that it can be remembered.

The links that select the different stylesheets, in my `<body>` tag look like this.

```
<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('purple'); return false;">purple</a>
<a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('red'); return false;">red</a>
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. The stylesheet doesn't change. See it in action here - or not as the case is!

http://uni.michaelnorris.co.uk/

Comment: Are both stylesheets applied? or just the style2 styles applied?

Comment: Originally I had the default 'style.css' stylesheet and the alternate 'alt_style1.css' stylesheet, but I added a truly persistent stylesheet and two others which just alternate with colours. All that happens is that nothing changes.

Comment: The link you added works fine for me in Firefox 7.0.1 on Linux.

Comment: Shouldn't this work in Safari then? That is what I am using. I have just tested it in Firefox and it works... So why not in Safari? Another note, how can I make the style.css be persistent, and just switch the alternate ones?

Comment: The link you provided has no alternate stylesheets at the moment. If you still need your question answered please update the link, or make a jsfiddle/jsbin test case.